# How can I detect if it is a negation with a verb in a sentence using spacy(or other library)?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy

..Hello Everybody! I'm working on an NLP project, and I want to detect if there is a negation with a given verb in a sentence

For example : the function "Is_there_negation" should return "True" with the following parameters :

```
text:"I don't want to eat right now"
verb:"eat"
```

How can I complete this function(I'm really beginner in NLP)

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")


def Is_there_negation(doc,verb):
    for token in doc :
        if(token.dep_=="neg" and token.head.text==verb):
            return True

        elif(token.text==verb):
            for tk in token.subtree:
                .
                .
                .

    return False
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is quite tricky. From the syntactic point of view, *eat* is not negated in the sentence, it is the auxiliary word *want* that is negated as you can see in a dependency parse of the sentence.

[image]

What might do the job is:

1. Find a negative particle (with dependency label `neg`)
2. Look what it is its dependency parent. If it is the verb you are looking for, return true.
3. If not, list descendants of the verb and have a look if the verb you are looking for is in the subtree (i.e, has the correct lemma and is tagged as a `VERB`). You might want however to limit the search to some subtree depth to ignore weird cases with too complicated phrases.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. But I don't understand  the part 3 (what should  I do with descendants of the verb)..I updated my code .

Comment: Sorry for the typo, the sentence should make sense now.